# base_local_planer : max_rotational_vel limit exceed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently trying to set up the navigation stack for a hexapod bot.

I already reached to sent simple goals and reach them, even if the behavior can be improved, but the base_local_planer actually doesn't take care of my max_rotational_vel limit, which I set to 0.2.
Having a look on the /cmd_vel topic , the planer seems to ignore my limit and sent with the default value 1.0 rad/sec.
Whereas the max_vel_x limit works fine.

Does anyone had the same problem ? Is there maybe a bug or did I do something wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62220/base_local_planer-:-max_rotational_vel-limit-exceed/) by [luc-weydert](https://answers.ros.org/users/4833/luc-weydert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc-weydert](https://answers.ros.org/users/4833/luc-weydert/) on 2013-05-06**:
Hi again, I figured out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again, I figured out what the problem was.

Having a look at the source code , I found out that the parameter isn't called like listed in the doc, but has a different name :
max_vel_theta

---

Originally posted by [luc-weydert](https://answers.ros.org/users/4833/luc-weydert/) with karma: 66 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3